# Appending TextView data to ListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-listview

I have parsed XML data in a TextView, but I need those data in a ListView. How do I append those data to a ListView? I've put the XML data into a string. Do I need to use an ArrayAdapter or an Array?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

List<XmlValuesModel> myData = null;
int     id;
boolean feedContents;
String  sport;
String OutputData="Sports";
Object obj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    final TextView output       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    final Button bparsexml      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bparsexml);




    final String XMLData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +

            "<sports>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<sport>\n" +
            "<id>1</id>\n" +
            "<feedContents>0</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Badminton</name>\n" +
            "</sport>\n" +

            "<id>16</id>\n" +
            "<feedContents>0</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Futsal</name>\n" +
            "</sport>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<sport>\n" +
            "<id>17</id>\n" +
            "<feedContents>0</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Golf</name>\n" +
            "</sport>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<sport>\n" +
            "<id>18</id>\n" +
            "<feedContents>0</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Handball</name>\n" +
            "</sport>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<sport>\n" +
            "<id>19</id>\n" +
            "<feedContents>0</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Hockey</name>\n" +
            "</sport>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<sport>\n" +
            "<feedContents>1</feedContents>\n" +
            "<name>Aussie Rules</name></sport>\n" +
            "</sports>\n" +

            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n";
    String dataToBeParsed = "Click on button to parse XML.\n\n XML DATA : \n\n"+XMLData;
    output.setText(dataToBeParsed);

    bparsexml.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try{

                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new StringReader(XMLData));
                InputSource is=new InputSource(br);

                //InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("sports1.xml");
                 //raw =getAssets().open("sports1.xml");
                XMLParser parser=new XMLParser();
                SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp=factory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader reader=sp.getXMLReader();
                reader.setContentHandler(parser);
                reader.parse(is);

               myData=parser.list;

                if(myData!=null){

                    for (XmlValuesModel xmlRowData : myData) {
                        if(xmlRowData!=null&&obj!=xmlRowData)
                        {

                            obj=xmlRowData;

                            id              = xmlRowData.getId();
                            feedContents    = xmlRowData.getFeedContents();
                            sport           = xmlRowData.getSport();




                            OutputData =OutputData+ "\n "+ id +" | "
                                    + feedContents +" | "+sport;



                           // Log.d("TAG ID",""+id);
                           // Log.d("TAG FEED",""+feedContents);
                            //Log.d("TAG Sport",sport);

                        }
                        //else
                            //Log.e("Sports", "Internal server error");
                    }
                    output.setText(OutputData);


                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Sports", "Exception parse xml :"+e);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you:

1) To create a model class for your data, i.e:

```
public class Sport{
   public int id;
   public String name;
   public String feedContents;
 ....
}
```

2) Parse your xml file to an `ArrayList` of `Sport` object.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) you can find how to do that.

3) Create a custom adapter for your `ListView`, and use your `ArrayList` of `Sport` objects as data.